# Calling Javascript Files Sequentially With JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Say I have the following array:

```
var array=['script1.js', 'script2.js','script3.js','script1.js']
```

How can I run through that array loading in each script one by one with the next one only being called after the previous one has been fully loaded and fired?

I wish to use JQuery's getScript function.

Would something like this suffice?

```
var i=0;
var id_key='file'+i;
function load_script(url){
$.getScript(url)
.done(i++; load_script(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar! You'll need a function call in done()

Comment: A function call to what?

Comment: `$.getScript(url,function(){//load next});`

Comment: According to the Jquery site: "Success Callback

The callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed.". Is there a way around that?

Comment: @Nuvolari By the time, next request succeeds, the previously loaded script would most probably have executed, so is that an issue that your callback get called before the loaded script is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
var array = ['script1.js', 'script2.js', 'script3.js', 'script1.js'];

function load_scripts(array) {
    if (!array || !array.length) {
        return
    }
    $.getScript(array.shift(), function () {
        load_scripts(array);
    })
}
load_scripts(array)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uMRq6/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var i=1;
var id_key='file'+i;
function load_script(url){
  $.getScript(url)
  .done(
      function(data){
        switch(i){
          case 1://do blah blah
          case 2://do blah blah
        }
        i++;
        if(i<=array.length){
          load_script(array[i])
        }
      });
}
load_script(array[i]);
```